# Open in Google Maps App when clicking on Google control button.. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using google maps SDK in swift 4, everything is perfect, but..
I need to allow the user to tap on Google control button as the image below:

[Google control button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2jUI.png)

My question is how to drop the a marker from my app map to google maps app with specific coordinates.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot override that button.

You're better off using a different button that opens a url. as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open

You can then include the marker coordinates as a query in your url, which will add a marker to the map.
 eg. https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=-33.830114,151.219235

this is as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide